# Adding to JComboBox without using an array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

Is it possible to add a `String` to a `JComboBox` without using an array?  I have an adding button that should add to combo box after clicking on it but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DefaultComboBoxModel.addElement(E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html#addElement-E-).  More generally, see [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Comment: i tried it and it still give me "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 1):

Andrew is correct, you don't need to go to the model though. The `jComboBox` class provides an [addItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItem%28E%29) method for you.